# how to use parameters of class A in class B in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to take data from entries of `product` (name, price) and use them in `item` so I use that method but when I call `creat_item` python tells me that there is unfiled parameters I've thought of using the inheritances but I couldn't and also and also this code creates only the last object of `item` with low quality image

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# create a screen and a main frame
screen = Tk()
screen.title("Buyer")
screen.geometry("800x600")
w = Frame(screen)
w.grid(padx=1, pady=1)
w.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# add images to the products
def Add_image(sender, row):
    image = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/yasse/OneDrive/Documents", filetypes=(("all", "*.*"),
                                                         ("PNG", "*.png"), ("JPEG", "*.jpeg"), ("GIF", "*.gif")))
    img = Image.open(image).resize(size=(120, 100))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    btn = ttk.Button(w, image=photo)
    btn.image = photo
    btn.grid(column=0, row=row)
    sender.destroy()
    # create a global var to use in Item
    global picture
    picture = photo

# create a class of the products for the buyer interface
class ITEM:
    def __init__(self, image,  name, price, buy):
        self.image = image
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.buy = buy
    # display the items in the buyer interface
    def item_row(self, row):
        self.image.configure(image=picture)
        self.image.grid(column=1, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.name.grid(column=2, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.price.grid(column=3, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.buy.grid(column=4, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)

# create a function that takes data from the products and create items with that data
def create_item(name, price):
    image_btn = Button(w, state=DISABLED)
    name_lbl = Label(w, text=name.get(), font=("helvetica", 16))
    price_lbl = Label(w, text=price.get(), font=("helvetica", 16))
    buy_btn = Button(w, text="buy", font=("helvetica", 16))
    return ITEM(image_btn, name_lbl, price_lbl, buy_btn)
# create a buyer inteface
def buying():
    #rename the screen
    screen.title("buying mode")
    #delet all the screen widgets
    for widget in w.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    # add the items to the interface
    (columns, rows) = w.grid_size()
    row = rows + 1
    prd = create_item()
    prd.item_row(row=row)

# create a class of raw products for the seller
class PRODUCT:
    def __init__(self, image, name, price, quantity, save):
        self.image = image
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.save = save
    def product_row(self, row):
        self.image.configure(command=lambda: Add_image(self.image, row))
        self.save.configure(command=lambda: create_item(self.name, self.image))
        self.image.grid(column=0, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.name.grid(column=1, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.price.grid(column=2, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.quantity.grid(column=3, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.save.grid(column=4, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
# create the raw product
def create_product():
    add_image = Button(w, text="+", font=("helvetica", 30))
    add_name = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 16))
    add_price = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 16), width=5)
    add_quantity = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 16), width=5)
    save = Button(w, text="save item", font=("helvetica", 13))
    return PRODUCT(add_image, add_name, add_price, add_quantity, save)
# create a new raw product
def new_product():
    (columns, rows) = w.grid_size()
    row = rows+1
    prd = create_product()
    prd.product_row(row=row)
# create the seller interface 
def selling():
    # delete the widgets 
    buying_button.destroy()
    selling_button.destroy()
    screen.title("selling mode")
    # create a button to switch between the modes 
    btn = Button(w, text="switch", command=buying).grid(row=0, column=2, pady=15, padx=30)
    # create a button to creat new products
    btn = Button(w, text="new product", command=new_product).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=15, padx=30)
# create buttons to enter to each interface
buying_button = Button(w, text="buyer mode", font=("helvetica", 16), width=16, height=2)
selling_button = Button(w, text="seller mode", font=("helvetica", 16), width=16, height=2, command=selling)
selling_button.pack()
buying_button.pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined

```
def create_item(name, price):
```

and later tried to call it with

```
    prd = create_item()
```

That won't work, as the call does not
match the function definition.
Supply both of the required parameters,
perhaps with e.g.

```
    prd = create_item('widget', 7)
```

Perhaps you want `buying()` to accept
arguments which would help in filling
in the name and price.

Comment: well I know that but I can't figure out a solution can you be more precise